# How to Generate A Particular Sound Frequency?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Application.I want to generate Sound of Frequency Ranges between 1KHz to 20KHz. is there anyway to generate sound at a specific Frequency.

Comment: The range you describe is not ultrasonic. I.e. it can still be heard.

Comment: Just nitpicking: ultrasonic _starts_ at 20KHz. Frequencies in the range you want are acoustic.

Comment: @alextsc, If it is in BlackBerry or in Java-ME, then also answer is welcome.

Comment: Take a look at [android.media.ToneGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html)

Comment: To be fair, most adults can not hear above 18khz (to many rock concerts)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this code from another SO post. from what I can tell it is still a little buggy but it should do the trick.

```
public class PlaySound extends Activity {
    // originally from http://marblemice.blogspot.com/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html
    // and modified by Steve Pomeroy <steve@staticfree.info>
    private final int duration = 3; // seconds
    private final int sampleRate = 8000;
    private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
    private final double freqOfTone = 440; // hz

    private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Use a new tread as this can take a while
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                genTone();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        playSound();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    void genTone(){
        // fill out the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
        }

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

        }
    }

    void playSound(){
        final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        audioTrack.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh. I just found the same thing [here](http://marblemice.blogspot.com/2010/04/generate-and-play-tone-in-android.html). Supposedly the code is updated at that link to fix the bugs.

Comment: Yeah but according to the comments it still has some... Either way it is a great base.

Comment: There is a problem with this code as it doesn't play back anything over 17000Hz even if you set sampleRate = 44100. These same algorithms work in Flash for example and the phone I am using can play these frequencies when they are coming from the file. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @Reid Unfortunately this code no longer works with newer versions of Android.