# Generate High frequency sound on android

Tags: android, audio

I want to generate sound pulses of 19khz on android for some hardware.
can android device generate 19k freq sound?
I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698633/how-to-generate-a-particular-sound-frequency)

but one person is saying that this method doesn't generate frequency beyond 17k.

Comment: I could image that if you generate a .wav file using the given link and then open that .wav file with [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) it might work.

Comment: Unless you are a young child or a dog, you won't be able to hear a tone at 19kHz, even assuming your phone speaker's frequency response passes it through.

Comment: I suspect the OP is wanting to do audio steganography.  The odds of getting this to work reliably from a phone speaker are slim at 19kHz. Especially on 'land-fill android' devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you can generate any frequency lower than sampleRate/2. If your samplerate is 44100 Hz, then you could generate up to 22500 Hz sounds.

I haven't checked the algorithm on the link, but it should be easy to copy-paste on a project and test.

Comment: In terms of data, yes. What makes it through the DSP stack, the DAC, the amplifier, and is efficiently trasnduced and radiated by the speaker is likely somewhat lower.  However, the specific goal here has a fairly high chance of working.