# Android play sound until explicitly stopped

Tags: android, timer, frequency, audiotrack

Somebody has already written code for generation a tone with a particular frequency for a given time. The SO link is given here: [How to Generate A Particular Sound Frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698633/how-to-generate-a-particular-sound-frequency).

What I need is, to play the sound indefinitely and not for 3 seconds. I want the sound to stop playing when a button is clicked or something like that. I was thinking maybe I can use timer function to repeat the same loop over and over. When the user clicks 'stop' button I want to invoke audiotrack.pause or stop. Is this a good way to go about it or is there a better logic for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Boggartfly but I found a much simpler solution. I can simply loop the audiotrack object.

I used the following code.

```
         audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, generatedSnd.length/4, -1);
```

The start frame is zero. The end frame is length/4 for 16bit PCM. The negative 1 here means loop infinite times.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

```
//Declare a new object

MediaPlayer Mp3=new MediaPlayer();

//Then set path of file
Mp3.setDataSource(“sdcard/filename.mp3”);

//Before playing audio, call prepare
Mp3.prepare();

//For Looping (true = looping; false = no looping)
Mp3.setLooping(true);

//To play audio ,call
Mp3.start();

//To pause, call
Mp3.pause

//To stop audio, call
Mp3.stop();
```

That's it done!

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to play any file. I want to generate a tone with a certain frequency. I am not sure if I can use mediaplayer.

Comment: @Susheel Well combine them. Pass arguments to MediaPlayer from the other class.  The other class will act as a source for MediaPlayer.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: The only method that sets source in mediaplayer seems to be setdatasource. I am not sure how to set the generated sample data(which is in bytes) as input to the mediaplayer. Any thoughts?

Comment: Write the data into a temporary mp3 file. Then pass that file into the MediaPlayer.

Comment: Also, I am not able to set Datasource as I get some exception:setDatasourcefd failed, status- 0x80000000. Thanks for your help though. I upvoted your answer but I found out a much simpler solution.