# Play specific sound frequency on Android

Tags: java, android, generator, midi

I need to play a specific sound frequency with a specific duration time.

Something like:

MyPlayer.play(440,1000);

Where '440' is the frequency in HZ
And '1000' is the duration in milisecs.

Is there any library I can use to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Check these links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106276/android-how-to-generate-a-frequency & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698633/how-to-generate-a-particular-sound-frequency

Answer (score -2):

Android has methods to play frequencies.  They are listed in the API.  Here you go.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html

Comment: And where can you specify 440 Hz?

Comment: int TONE_SUP_CONFIRM Call supervisory tone (IS-95), confirm tone: a 350 Hz tone added to a 440 Hz tone repeated 3 times in a 100 ms on, 100 ms off cycle

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html#TONE_SUP_INTERCEPT